# Why do Facebook capabilities stop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to allow users of my iOS app to choose a picture form their Facebook pictures with a graph API call. I do this by querying for the album IDs then by searching through those albums. The album query works. However, if I close to app completely (by deleting it from currently open apps), I can no longer make the call. If I just close the app and re-open it, it works fine. This only happens when I completely close the app. Is there a way around this?

Here is the code I use to make the call to get albums:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/albums"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if (!error) {
                              NSLog(@"Results: %@", result);
                          }
                      }
 ];
```

Again, the issue is that when I close the app, double-click the home button, and completely close my app, then re-open it, this call does not work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your session state when the app opens again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your facebook session has closed.  Try adding this line when the app opens:

```
if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    [FBSession.activeSession openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {
      // perform action that you want to happen when FB session opens like a segue
    }];
}
```

For more on sessions go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/session/

Comment: Good info. However, I don't want the users to have to login every single time. Isn't there something about caching a session token that I need to do?

Comment: The Facebook SDK manages the token for you in the session. You interact with the session through methods like this. Once they have "logged in" the session can still be closed. You don't need them to do any particular action to re-open the session. Instead just call this method in a view did load or wherever is appropriate in your program under the hood. Thus a closed session is different than being "logged out."